# В чем проблема? регистрация формы

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    print("у вас нет аккаунта,создать новый? да/нет"),
dn=input("введиди")
if ((dn=="нет") or ("Нет")):
    break
elif((dn=="да") or ("Да")):
    login=input("придумайте логин(имя):")
    password=input("придумайте пароль:")
vhod=input("хотите войти? да/нет")
if((vhod=="нет") or ("Нет")):
    break 
elif((vhod=="да") or (vhod=="Да")):
    testlogin=input("логин:")
    testpassword=input("пароль:")
    if((testlogin==login) and (testpassword==password)):
        print("приветствую мой повелитель!")
    elif((not(testlogin==login)) and (testpassword==password)):
        print("неверное имя!")
    elif((not(testpassword==password)) and(testlogin==login)):
        print("неверный пароль!")
    elif((not(testlogin==login) and (testpassword==password))
        print("неверное имя и пароль!")
        break 
else:
    print("___неизвестное значение, выход... :( ___")
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых `while(True)` у вас заканчивается на следующей строке - ведь 3 строка начинается без отступа уже - это основная ошибка

если это исправить, то в строке

```
elif((not(testlogin==login) and (testpassword==password))
```

отсутствует `:` - это вторая ошибка

и отсутствует закрывающая скобка - это третья ошибка

должно быть так:

```
elif((not(testlogin==login) and (testpassword==password))):
```

на последней строчке `break` стоит зазря - поскольку конструкция `while() else` внутри `else` не требует `break` - это четвертая ошибка